# Detecting breaks/changes in formatting of a date column

Tags: r, date

I was wondering if anyone knows about a package or function that can detect any breaks in the formatting of a date column in R. i.e detecting the location of the change in formatting of a date vector like:

```
11/2/90
12/2/90
.
.
.
15/Feb/1990
16/Feb/1990
.
.
.
20/February/90
21/February/90
.
.
.
25/2/1990
26/2/1990
```

Comment: Could you be more precise in the types of breaks you want to detect? Here, you just have to check the change in the string size in your vector... You can simply do it with the function `nchar`

Comment: I was looking for a way to detect a change from any formatting to any other, I hadn't thought of using nchar, but is there not anything more specific? This wouldn't pick up a difference between 11/Feb/90 and 11/2/1990

Comment: I do not know specific things. But you may handle situations like these with regular expressions and associated R functions (like grep): http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: Parse the dates with formats "%d/%m/%y", "%d/%b/%y", "%d/%B/%y" and look at the NAs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you only need to detect the breaks or do you eventually want to convert these too?

The `guess_formats` function from package `lubridate` can be useful in both cases. See this example from your data:

```
dates = c("11/2/90",
          "12/2/90",
          "15/Feb/1990",
          "16/Feb/1990",
          "20/February/90",
          "21/February/90",
          "25/2/1990",
          "26/2/1990")

guess_formats(dates, order="dmy")
       dmy        dmy        dmy        dmy        dmy        dmy        dmy        dmy 
"%d/%m/%y" "%d/%m/%y" "%d/%b/%Y" "%d/%b/%Y" "%d/%B/%y" "%d/%B/%y" "%d/%m/%Y" "%d/%m/%Y"

dates2 = as.Date(dates, format=guess_formats(dates, order="dmy")
dates2
[1] "1990-02-11" "1990-02-12" "1990-02-15" "1990-02-16" "1990-02-20" "1990-02-21" "1990-02-25" "1990-02-26"
```

Comment: +1,hadley's packages are like magic hats, always pop out nifty tricks!

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as asb's solution, using base R functions:

```
txt<-readLines(textConnection("11/2/90
12/2/90
15/Feb/1990
16/Feb/1990
20/February/90
21/February/90
25/2/1990
26/2/1990"))

#split date and check length of each element(day,month,year)
len_list<-lapply(strsplit(txt,split="/"),nchar)
[[1]]
[1] 2 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 2 8 2

[[6]]
[1] 2 8 2

[[7]]
[1] 2 1 4

[[8]]
[1] 2 1 4

#Sum of lengths of elements, difference in sum implies, format break
sum_list<-lapply(len_list,sum)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 9

[[4]]
[1] 9

[[5]]
[1] 12

[[6]]
[1] 12

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 7
#index of format breaks
idx<-which(unlist(lapply(2:length(sum_list),function(x) unlist(sum_list[x-1])!=unlist(sum_list[x]))))
[1] 2 4 6
#dates at format breaks
txt[idx]
[1] "12/2/90"        "16/Feb/1990"    "21/February/90"
```